# jQuery fadeOut problem

Tags: jquery

I am making a site that requires the content area of the site be faded out when the user clicks a btn. The btn is a simple anchor tag. I have had some help from other S.O users on this and nearly got it working just fine. The problem I have is that it will not fade out. Here is the jquery code:

```
$("#show-background").click(function () {
if ($("#content-area").hasClass("bg_hidden")){
    $("#content-area")
    .removeClass("bg_hidden")
    .stop()
    .fadeIn("slow");
    $(this).text("Show Background");
          }
else{
    $("#content-area")
    .addClass("bg_hidden")
    .stop()
    .fadeOut("slow");
     $(this).text("Show Text");
          }
});
```

A sample can be found here www.nicklansdell.com/sample/services.html I wonder if any one can help? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use toggle?

```
$("#show-background").click(function () {
    $("#content-area").animate({opacity: 'toggle'}, 'slow'); 
});
```

Comment: `fadeToggle` is not in the jquery API.

Comment: The reason why I was given this method was to break it down so I could understand how it works, which of course now I do now :) When I try your method it simply doesn't work. I am wondering if the Jquery tools library is somehow conflicting with this code?

Comment: I edited to animate that is a libary in the core this should work.

Comment: Just tried the above and what happens now is when the btn is clicked it just fades in repeatedly

Comment: I just tested the code myself and it works perfectly. Make sure the #showbackground id is used on 1 element and that there is not other library interfering with it. Here a link to the working script:
http://dreu.info/tests/fadetoggle.html

Comment: please vote for what answer was helpfull by upvoting it. That makes us feel warm inside. :P

Comment: I will still trying all answers none are working for me! Its driving me crazy I've obviously screwed up somewhere but god only knows! Anyways I can the answer you gave does definitely work so....

Comment: Try to disable that jquery tools and see if it then works. If it does there is a similar library made by jquery themselfes named jquery-ui. This library makes sure it doesn't interfere with jqueries core features

Comment: Yeah I very briefly looked at it but decided on Tools because of the scrollable feature with UI doesn't seem to have. Will look again though.

Comment: The problem is you are using the jQuery Tools which includes jQuery, but it's not version 1.4 which is the only version that supports the opacity 'toggle'.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fade out separately from addClass:

```
$("#content-area").fadeOut("slow");
```

BTW, you can check the button's text in the `if` instead of class existence...

Comment: Hi I tried doing this but again it did not work. Could there be a conflict between my code here and the jquery tools library I am using?

Answer (score 0):

I did some tries on your page with firebug and couldn't come up with what is breaking the `fadeOut` call.

If you need a workaround, you can do:

```
if ($("#content-area").hasClass("bg_hidden")){
    $("#content-area")
    .removeClass("bg_hidden")
    .stop()
    .children().fadeIn("slow");
    $(this).text("Show Background");
}else{
    $("#content-area")
    .addClass("bg_hidden")
    .stop()
    .children().fadeOut("slow");
     $(this).text("Show Text");
}
```

Fading in/out all the children worked on your page.

This is a *work-around*, not a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the Alex. When I try this and preview it the div#content-area is hidden from the start and the btn does not work. Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?